# Make slider respond to html5 audio timeupdate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've created a slider for an html5 audio player using the jQuery UI. The problem I'm having is that the slider itself does not respond to time changes (`timeupdate`) in the track itself. It does however respond to dragging the slider and the song and `time` also respond to this by changing the time of the audio.

To me it seems that the slider is being affected by something else when the track is playing as there is a constant `left: 0%` style on the slider when playing even though the jQuery states this should change. When I set the jQuery to `right: pos +'%` the right style changes dynamically with the audio but the `left: 0%` style remains. There are no errors shown in the console so i've really no idea whats going on.

```
$(song).on('timeupdate', function() {

  var rem = parseInt(song.duration - song.currentTime, 10),
  pos = (song.currentTime / song.duration) * 100,
  mins = Math.floor(rem/60,10),
  secs = rem - mins*60;

  $('.body_container .player .time').text('-' + mins + ':' + (secs > 9 ? secs : '0' + secs));
  if(manualSeek = true){$('.body_container .player .ui-slider-handle').css({left: pos + '%'}); }
  if (loaded = true) {
  loaded = true;

    $('.body_container .player .slider').slider({

      max: song.duration,

      slide: function() {             
        manualSeek = true;
      },
      stop:function(e,ui) {
        manualSeek = false;         
        song.currentTime = ui.value;
      }

    });
   }

});
```

**Side note:** Just thought i'd say as someone asked this on a previous question. `song` is defined I just haven't included it as its not needed. `song = new Audio(url);` where `url` is the track url got from the data-attribute of the player.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 'bind' instead of 'on'? ex: `$(song).bind('timeupdate',function(){})`

"on" I think is for event delegation of click events.